# iPhone UIPickerView in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, sdk, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I have a xib in which I have added a `UIViewController` named delta. The view under delta is controlled by the delta viewcontroller, not the file owner. On the delta view, I have a `UIViewPicker`. My issue is that I am programming in the `UIPickerView` in the `deltaviewcontroller` and I'm issuing `deltaviewcontroller` as the delegate and data source for the `UIPickerView`. Everything should work, but when I load the deltaviewcontroller's view, the application crashes. If I carry out everything the same way under the file's owner view, it works fine. I'm wondering if there is really a way to make the UIPickerView work with a `UIViewController` and no necessarily a file's owner.

For references, the code:

Header

```
@interface DeltaViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *arrayNo;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayNo;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "DeltaViewController.h"

@implementation DeltaViewController

@synthesize pickerView;
@synthesize arrayNo;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *dollarsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        NSString *item = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        [dollarsArray addObject:item];
    }

    self.arrayNo = dollarsArray;

    [dollarsArray release]; 
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [arrayNo count];
}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [arrayNo release];
    [pickerView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Please point out if I'm doing anything wrong. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: This code looks ok other than that you are leaking the "item" string. What is the actual crash/exception that you are getting? Can you describe and show the code for loading/displaying the delta view controller?

Comment: Open the console from the Run menu and tell us the error you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search how to add a UIPickerView in a UIView, just check out the Apple sample code for UIPickerView. I think it's one of the best ways learning to use the different classes correctly. There are five project which includes an UIPickerView. Here's the link

[UIPickerView class reference and sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing
     [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
   in your viewDidLoad  method.